# How to rewrite a has_many using a scope block?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

The declaration:

```
  has_many :read_access_mappings, 
           :primary_key => "username", 
           :foreign_key => "username", 
           :class_name => 'Mapping',
           :conditions => {"mappings.read_access" => true}
```

got a warning:

> DEPRECATION WARNING: The following options in your User.has_many
>   :read_access_mappings declaration are deprecated: :conditions. Please
>   use a scope block instead.

How can I rewrite it in the new syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best solution:

```
class Cls
 has_many :readable_mappings,
          -> { readable },
          primary_key: 'username',
          foreign_key: 'username',
          class_name: 'Mapping'
end

class Mapping
  scope :readable, where(read_access: true)
end

cls_instance.readable_mappings
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps You can try this:

```
has_many :read_access_mappings, -> { where read_access: true },class_name: 'Mapping',
           primary_key => "username", 
           foreign_key => "username"
```

[Source](https://github.com/collectiveidea/awesome_nested_set/issues/170)